# How to decrypt an 'encrypted file by openssl' in java

Tags: java, android, linux, openssl

I've encrypted a file on linux with the following openssl command:

**openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -in file.xml -out -file.xml.aes -pass pass:password**

Now I'm looking to decrypt this file in a java application.

Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're having trouble with. Use the `KeyGenerator` class to generate a `SecretKey`.

Comment: I haven't used any key while encrypting the file.

It was encrypted with only a password

Comment: Is there any particular reason for letting openssl derive the key for you? If this is a requirement, then I guess you'll have to look into [how openssl derives keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/35614#35614) from passwords to try to replicate that.

Comment: Actually the goal is to have a simple encryption method that can be easily decrypt on different platforms such as linux, windows and Androïd.

I found that openssl was doing password based encryption and was known on theses differents platforms, that's why I decided to go with it.